# Load the data in to the respective textview

Tags: android

When I run this I can show the description in a textview (only that textview is there in the whole screen) but i want to show that in the textview grid_text, which is a item in my xml file (activity_viewmore, it has couple of textviews and other stuff).

```
public class viewmore extends Activity {

    TextView descriptionTV;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmore);

        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");

        descriptionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);


        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(10);
        textView.setText(description);

        setContentView(textView);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

why you are updating your UI twice. You are calling `setContentView()` two times . So when you run this you get to see the one executed later which contains only TextView . What you are trying to achieve can be done as:

```
public class viewmore extends Activity {

    TextView descriptionTV;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmore);

        String description = getIntent().getStringExtra("description");
        String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUrl");

        descriptionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);

        descriptionTV .setText(description);

    }
```

Comment: that worked. how can i load the images? when I used this imageUrlIV.setImageResource(imageUrl); -- it gives error for setImageResource

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understood your problem you simply want to apply the description to the TextView in your layout instead of filling the whole screen with the newly created view.

You already got everything you need to do that.
You're referencing the proper TextView with findViewById and saving it to descriptionTV.
So instead of creating the new TextView you could call the "setText(description)" on the descriptionTV. 
The problem with "only that textview is there in the whole screen" is your last line of code where you're saying that the newly created TextView should be the ContentView.

So

```
descriptionTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grid_text);
descriptionTV.setText(description);
```

should do the job when you're removing

```
setContentView(textView);
```

because this call overwrites your layout that you setup before

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_viewmore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my low reputation I am not able to answer to your comment, so I am adding another answer.

> that worked. how can i load the images? when I used this
>   imageUrlIV.setImageResource(imageUrl); -- it gives error for
>   setImageResource –  John David

What kind of error do you get and which type is the imageUrl of?

setImageResource() only accepts an android resource typeof integer. (R.drawable.test_image)

Comment: I was able to find the answer.. which is         ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_image); 
        Picasso.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(imageView);